# Is it Possible to Join these 2 Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, join, between

I have 2 tables

Table A:

```
+------------+----------+
| Entry From | Entry To |
+------------+----------+
|        100 |      103 |
|        104 |      105 |
|        106 |      109 |
+------------+----------+
```

Table B:

```
+-------+-------+
| Entry | Value |
+-------+-------+
|   100 |    10 |
|   101 |     3 |
|   102 |     7 |
|   103 |     2 |
|   104 |     9 |
|   105 |    17 |
|   106 |     3 |
|   107 |     3 |
|   108 |     6 |
|   109 |     5 |
+-------+-------+
```

Desired result:

```
+------------+----------+-------------+
| Entry From | Entry To | Total Value |
+------------+----------+-------------+
|        100 |      103 |          22 |
|        104 |      105 |          26 |
|        106 |      109 |          17 |
+------------+----------+-------------+
```

Any solutions/advice is welcome.

Thanks to any help in advance!

Comment: In table_b, which column does "entry" map to?  Is it entry_from or entry_to?

Comment: This is the problem - I want it to map if it is between entry from or entry to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
Select 
    a.EntryFrom, a.EntryTo, sum(Value) TotalValue 
From TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b ON b.Entry between a.EntryFrom and a.EntryTo 
Group by a.EntryFrom, a.EntryTo
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all 3 answers! As this was the first I will mark this as the accepted answer. Only problem is that the query seems to be taking a long time to execute, is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a subquery maybe.

```
SELECT 
    A.Entry_From, A.Entry_To, 
    (SELECT SUM(B.Value) FROM B 
        WHERE B.Entry BETWEEN A.Entry_From AND A.Entry_To) AS Total_Value
    FROM A
```

It also depends on what version of SQL so YMMV :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afbac/2 using this query:

```
select a.idxFrom, a.idxTo, sum(b.value) as total
from a inner join b on b.idx >= a.idxFrom and b.idx <= a.idxTo
group by a.idxFrom, a.idxTo
```